# gdal doesn't support *XYZ-file

Tags: gdal, dem, geotiff-tiff, convert, saga

I have just exported a TIF DEM to XYZ format with SAGA GIS. When I check this with gdalinfo it states that the format is unsupported.

Seeing as I converted this with SAGA GIS which used gdal I find this rather strange.

Can anyone suggest what I did wrong?

Answer (score 6):

GDAL's XYZ driver is not particularly robust (e.g. "Ungridded dataset: At line 3, change of Y direction" with a perfectly gridded dataset), so here are a few alternative methods that should yield the same result.

## Using Python

Most of the array look-ups are done with pandas. This method is probably the fastest.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
from affine import Affine

dat = pd.read_table("file.xyz", sep=" ", header=None, dtype=float, low_memory=False)
xmin = dat[0].min()
xmax = dat[0].max()
ymin = dat[1].min()
ymax = dat[1].max()
dx = dat[0].drop_duplicates().sort_values().diff().median()
dy = dat[1].drop_duplicates().sort_values().diff().median()
xv = pd.Series(np.arange(xmin, xmax + dx, dx))
yv = pd.Series(np.arange(ymin, ymax + dy, dy)[::-1])
xi = pd.Series(xv.index.values, index=xv)
yi = pd.Series(yv.index.values, index=yv)
nodata = -9999.
zv = np.ones((len(yi), len(xi)), np.float32) * nodata
zv[yi[dat[1]].values, xi[dat[0]].values] = dat[2]

# register geotransform based on upper-left corner
transform = Affine(dx, 0, xmin, 0, -dy, ymax) * Affine.translation(-0.5, -0.5)
with rasterio.open("file.tif", "w", "GTiff", len(xi), len(yi), 1, "EPSG:????",
                   transform, rasterio.float32, nodata) as ds:
    ds.write(zv.astype(np.float32), 1)
```

## Using R via [`sp` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/)

This method probably takes the most memory to process. From an R console:

```
library(sp)
dat <- read.table("file.xyz")
coordinates(dat) <- ~V1+V2
gridded(dat) <- TRUE
write.asciigrid(dat, "file.asc")
```

Then re-write this as a GeoTIFF from a console:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:???? file.asc file.tif
```

Comment: Python version - dat[0] syntax only works if there is no header row. Use dat.iloc[:,0] instead

Comment: Python version (Jan 2021) - rasterio 1.2.0 doesn't work in a script but 1.1.8 does - 1.2.0 can't find the crs database.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the compression of the exported GeoTiff from the python rasterio function?

Comment: @miln40 yes, just pass them as keyword arguments to `open()`; [see docs](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/image_options.html)

Answer (score 4):

Since you exported a DEM, I'm assuming you had gridded data in your XYZ, and it's reasonable to expect that `gdal_translate` would have handled it.  I'm guessing that the problem is that SAGA exports XYZ with only the good points from your grid, and not the missing data points.  It seems that `gdal_translate` needs all the points from the grid in order to work. I wrote this little python script to convert some similar XYZ data.  I haven't made this very flexible, but I'm sure you could modify it to fit your needs.  The Ipython Notebook version is here: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rsignell-usgs/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/files/xyz2tif.ipynb, and the plain ol' python code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# xyz2tif.py
# convert gridded XYZ data (but without missing values) to GeoTIFF
# data looks like this:
"""
379528.00 4577221.00 -5.38
379529.00 4577221.00 -5.38
379530.00 4577221.00 -5.40
379531.00 4577221.00 -5.41
379515.00 4577222.00 -5.34
379516.00 4577222.00 -5.36
"""

from pylab import *
from osgeo import osr,gdal

# UTM ZONE 19, NAD83 data
data =genfromtxt('/rps/bathy/muskegat/EW_Survey1.xyz')
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
z=data[:,2]

# find the extent and difference 
xmin=min(x);xmax=max(x)
ymin=min(y);ymax=max(y)
mdx=abs(diff(x))
mdy=abs(diff(y))

# determine dx and dy from the median of all the non-zero difference values
dx=median(mdx[where(mdx>0.0)[0]])
dy=median(mdy[where(mdy>0.0)[0]])

#construct x,y,z of complete grid
xi=arange(xmin,xmax+dx,dx)
yi=arange(ymin,ymax+dy,dy)
zi=ones((len(yi),len(xi)))*NaN
shape(zi)

# calculate indices in full grid (zi) to stick the input z values
ix=numpy.round((x-xmin)/dx).astype(int)
iy=numpy.round((y-ymin)/dy).astype(int)
zi[iy,ix]=z

zi=flipud(zi)

# write as 32-bit GeoTIFF using GDAL
ny,nx = zi.shape
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
ds = driver.Create('output.tif', nx, ny, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
ds.SetGeoTransform( [ xmin, dx, 0, ymax, 0, dy ] )

# set the reference info 
srs = osr.SpatialReference()

# UTM zone 19, North=1
srs.SetUTM(19,1)
srs.SetWellKnownGeogCS('NAD83')    
ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

# write the data to a single band
ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zi)
# close
ds = None
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also had problems with XYZ files not being recognized in gdal.  I don't necessarily think that you did anything wrong.  GDAL will only open gridded XYZ data files (see [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html)).  Ungridded XYZ files need to be handled in some other way.  I suspect (but don't know for sure) that what SAGA has exported is an ungridded XYZ format.

In my particular use-case, I had ungridded headerless XYZ files.  I worked around the problem by opening the XYZ file in a text editor and adding a header line in the format: x,y,z.  I then treated the file as a csv point dataset and used gdal_rasterize to convert to a raster.  I had a lot of files so I wrote a little Python script as a batch process.  I hope that helps.